# AutoMapper issue

Tags: asp.net, dto-mapping

Trying to automap some objects.
Source objects has properties with _ before name, destination objects - have not.
Is it possible to implement ONE map creation, that automapper would map all _properties to properties
for all source types.

```
class MyMapper<TFrom, TTo>{
    TTo PerformMap(TFrom fromObject){
        Mapper.CreateMap<From, To>(); // ???
        TTo result = Mapper.Map<From, To>(fromObject);
        //result.Id.ShouldBe(value from TFrom._Id);
        return result;
    }
}

class From
{
    public int _Id { get; set; }
    public string _Name { get; set; }
}

class To
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something I added recently to AutoMapper might help you - custom naming conventions.  If you check out the trunk (R107), look around for INamingConvention.  Right now, I have two naming conventions (PascalCase and lower_case_underscore), but it's really just a matter of figuring out the right RegEx to get you going:

[INamingConvention.cs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/INamingConvention.cs)

Right now, naming conventions are global and profile-scoped. Since this feature is new, there isn't any documentation other than the tests.

Comment: I'm not using AM at the moment, but nice to know about this feature. :)

Comment: the link in this answer gives a 404, can you please update?  Thanks for the awesome work Jimmy!

Comment: Does this work with IDataReader sources? I am trying to map DataTable in lower_case_underscore to an object w/ properties in PascalCase but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'm doing it

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RecognizeDestinationPrefixes(new []{"_"});
            cfg.RecognizePrefixes(new[] { "_" });

            cfg.CreateMap<To, From>().ReverseMap();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you could add a custom mapping to solve this particular case:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<From, To>()
   .ForMember( dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom( src => src._Id ) )
   .ForMember( dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom( src => src._Name ) );
```

Comment: That`s the effect i need, but... I wanted that to be more generic.
Like saying - automapper, map those 2 objects, and ignore underscore of prop name, if it`s first symbol in name. Otherwise - i have to pay attention for all object pairs.

Comment: This is unrealistic in real-world applications where there are potentially hundreds of POCOs