# How to make automapper ignore underscore?

Tags: automapper

I'm using automapper v1.1.

On my DB side, I have fields like this: manufacturer_id, manufacturer_name, ...

On my Dto side, I have fields like this: ManufacturerId, ManufacturerName, ...

How can I config automapper so that such mapping goes smoothly? Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft Enterprise Library DataAccess block. I know I can write sql to return "ManufacturerId", but I just wonder if automapper has such capability built in.

Comment: Answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732446/automapper-issue